# Conversion failed when converting the varchar to numeric and displaying numeric values only

Tags: sql

```sql
select * 
    ,iif (DAYSS>=1, DAYSS, 'Out of Stock') as NEWDA
    from TABLE3
```

got an  error

> converting data type varchar to numeric.

when tried to convert numeric to varchar but that is also an error

```sql
use case when isnumeric (DAYSS) >=0 then CAST(DAYSS as varchar)
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '7.350000' to data type int.

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SQL Server and MysQL are completely different. The error, however, *is* telling you the problem, `'7.350000'` isn't a valid `int` value; integers don't have decimal places.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, you might want to look into `try_convert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend `case` instead of `iif()`, but it is the same problem.  The expression refers to a single value, with a single type.  If one branch ("then") is a number and the other a string ("else"), then the result is a number.

So, convert the number to a string:

```
select t3.*,
       (case when DAYSS >= 1 then cast(DAYSS as varchar(255))
             else 'Out of Stock'
        end) as NEWDA
from TABLE3 t3;
```